# Area51 - my proposal from a few months ago was deleted, and now has been created by someone else?

Tags: support, area-51, duplicate-questions, site-proposal

Specifically, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24590/model-rocketry (Model Rocketry) is something I proposed a few months ago.

Recently it was deleted from Area51 (no idea why or by whom).

This morning I saw that someone else had created a new one (ref'd above).

So... what gives?

Comment: It's fair to say that if he was watching it more intently he would have known why. However, it's still a valid question. His site was deleted and he wants to know why. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original Model Rocketry proposal was created on July 27th and received 4 followers over the next eight days. After that, it received NO further activity for two months. It was deleted as part of the routine maintenance of Area 51. I will be adding more about the removal of inactive proposals to the Area 51 FAQ.

Of course, anyone is free to propose the site again if they feel they are better able to recruit a critical mass of supporters. But, if no further efforts are made to *promote* the site idea, the site isn't likely to be created by the current audience of Area 51.

Comment: good answer. I like the fact that you delete old proposals routinely. And what you say about starting it again.

Comment: @warren - this implies that it is probably best to try to make it wider this time - some kind of wide model / kit proposal?

Comment: we definitely *need* to update the FAQ about this

Answer (score 0):

The first incarnation of the proposal withered, whimpering in a corner clutching at napkins in trying to fashion a new hairpiece, and eventually [died off through lack of attention and promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66364/area-51-proposal-unceremoniously-deleted/66367#66367).

This fresh and new vision of the same old thing is trying to restrike the thunder with lightning applause and hopefully will do a better job of not dying than the first.

This is all so that an Area 51 site has the best chance of survival and isn't dragged through gravel and smallpox on account of a previously floated sinker.

> Feel free to re-create the proposal if you have reason to believe it will do better this time around. Situations change and people come across new resources and new ideas. But in terms of maintaining Area 51, I wouldn't like to see abandoned or stale proposals cited as a reason to close newer proposals made by people with renewed energy and, possibly, better resources to bring it to commitment.

Comment: This post is not offensive enough. Needs less diplomacy and more inyourfaceness

Comment: Right, @random, I upvote it anyway.